# Creating a zip archive from a folder and preserving structure with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, zipstream

I'm trying to use Node.js to create a zip file from an existing folder, and preserve the structure.

I was hoping there would be a simple module to allow this kind of thing:

```
archiver.create("../folder", function(zipFile){ 
    console.log('et viola');
});
```

but I can't find anything of the sort!

I've been googling around, and the best I've found so far is zipstream, but as far as I can tell there's no way to do what I want. I don't really want to call into commandline utilities, as the the app has to be cross platform.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely code free, but you can use [node-native-zip](https://github.com/janjongboom/node-native-zip) in conjunction with [folder.js](https://github.com/c9/azure-packager-node/blob/master/folder.js). Usage:

```
function zipUpAFolder (dir, callback) {
    var archive = new zip();

    // map all files in the approot thru this function
    folder.mapAllFiles(dir, function (path, stats, callback) {
        // prepare for the .addFiles function
        callback({ 
            name: path.replace(dir, "").substr(1), 
            path: path 
        });
    }, function (err, data) {
        if (err) return callback(err);

        // add the files to the zip
        archive.addFiles(data, function (err) {
            if (err) return callback(err);

            // write the zip file
            fs.writeFile(dir + ".zip", archive.toBuffer(), function (err) {
                if (err) return callback(err);

                callback(null, dir + ".zip");
            });                    
        });
    });    
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! The zip is created, but unfortunately it's corrupted and appears empty. I'll play around with it and try and see what the problem is.

Comment: Actually, it only seems to be *slightly* corrupted ;)
When I try and explore the created zip, it appears empty, but when I extract it, the contents look fine.

Thanks for a great, swift answer!

Answer (score 2):

This can be done even simpler using node's built-in execfile function. It spawns a process and executes the zip command through the os, natively. Everything just works.

```
var execFile = require('child_process').execFile;

execFile('zip', ['-r', '-j', zipName, pathToFolder], function(err, stdout) {
        console.log(err);
        logZipFile(localPath);
    });
```

The -j flag 'junks' the file path, if you are zipping a sibdirectory, and don't want excessive nesting within the zip file.

Here's [some documentation on execfile](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback).
Here's [a man page for zip](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/zip.1.html).

Comment: The op specifically said they wanted to native and cross platform and NOT a command line call.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Easy-zip](https://www.npmjs.org/package/easy-zip), `npm install easy-zip`,  you can do:

```
var zip5 = new EasyZip();
zip5.zipFolder('../easy-zip',function(){
    zip5.writeToFile('folderall.zip');
});
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using this because of [this issue](https://github.com/owenchong/easy-zip/issues/2).

Comment: I've been using `easy-zip` lately and haven't run into the issue that @rax highlighted.